# How to do cloud removal on composite imagery

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

I'm trying to get a state region of Sentinel-2 composite image from last year (2022-04-01, 2022-04-30). I did the normal cloud removal method based on QA band. The code is

```
Import roi
Import sentinel-2 L2A collection


//perform cloud removal
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}  

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-03-31')   //image time
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',40))  //cloud percentage
                  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', true)
                  .map(maskS2clouds)  //cloud removal
                  .map(function(image) {
                   var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('B5');
                   return image.addBands(ndvi);
                   })   //add index
                   .map(function(image){
                   var B1 = image.select("B2").rename("B1");//blue
                   var B2 = image.select("B3").rename("B2");//green
                   var B3 = image.select("B4").rename("B3");//red
                   var B4 = image.select("B8").rename("B4");//nir
                   return image.addBands(B1)
                               .addBands(B2)
                               .addBands(B3)
                               .addBands(B4)
                   })  //rename
                  .select(["B1","B2","B3","B4"/*,"B5","B6","B7","B8","B9"*/]); 
var study_img = dataset.median().clip(roi);  //clip the median composite image
Map.addLayer(study_img, {bands:["B4", "B3", "B2"], min:0, max:0.3}, 'RGB');
//
```

The results did do cloud removal, but only on one tile of the composite, as shown in the attached screenshot.

Does anyone know what's the problem and how to apply the cloud removal over the entire roi?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it was a cloudy month. Did you try this code for a longer temporal range?

Comment: You might want to check this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless

Comment: Here is an abridged version of the tutorial Johnathan linked to, in case it helps: https://gist.github.com/jdbcode/fc4a2d15bf26b4635860d3296cb78411